# Почему не все элементы загружаются в TableView

Tags: objective-c

Есть массив 119 элементов .Загружаю в TableView. В итоге загружаются только 14 элементов. Ошибок никаких нету.

```
dataArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:arr];

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return [dataArray count];
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
static NSString*cellid=@"Cell";
UITableViewCell*cell=[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellid];
if(cell==Nil){
cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellid];
}
cell.textLabel.text=[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема в том, что ячейки в таблице `reusable`.

Вот, что написано в [документации](https://developer.apple.com/reference/uikit/uitableviewcell?language=objc):

> The table view's delegate in tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath: should
>   always reset all content when reusing a cell.

Вы должны сбрасывать данные ячейки, пример:

```
 if(cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: cellid];
 } else {
    cell.textLabel.text = nil
 }
 cell.textLabel.text=[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

Comment: Получил пустую таблицу вставил этот код

Comment: f(cell == nil) {
cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle: UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: cellid];
} else {
cell.textLabel.text = nil;
}
return cell;
}

Comment: Пустая таблица потому што cell.textLabel.text = nil, вставте свои значения cell.textLabel.text=[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

Comment: Конечно пустая будет ;) Вы должны после того, как сделали сброс данных, поставить свои. Просто добавьте в Ваш код else из ответ

Comment: Дополнил ответ, чтобы было понятнее

Comment: Там еще return cell; добавить надо ошибку пишет; a так загружает 10 элементов, попробую на реальном девайсе